# backup using backups in preparation for installing LTS 22 (suitability?)

Tags: 20.04, backup, 22.04, restore

I'm wanting to do a clean installation of LTS 22 onto my box (desktop Thinkpad x220) and was seeking a best practice advice. I just tested the ISO installer and all good there. I have just used the "Backups" tool that was provided by the system when I installed 20, onto an external USB HDD. However I wonder if this is a suitable method to preserve my files because I see many system things appear in the dialog (watched it as it was scrolling).

Should I simply copy the $home folder instead?

I'm not wanting to bring any legacy applications or configurations which may interfere with the fresh install of 22

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. 20 & 22) are different products than those using the *year.month* format (eg. 20.04 & 22.04).   Please be precise with details.  You can re-install Ubuntu without losing files, or packages (if from Ubuntu repos) which includes swapping releases if you're talking about a desktop release (you don't specify).

Comment: dear @guiverc desktop is specified in the post, specific versions are in the tags 20.04 and moving to 22.04. How much more precision do I need? I don't know what you mean by "re install" as if I used the installation CD I'm pretty sure it will wipe the drive and I'll loose everything.
Your own post seems to be unhelpful and not actually answering anything. But thanks anyway.